# Negative packet loss in omnet

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am working on a smart home system with a lot of lamps and switches and a hub, using aodv routers. So i was trying to calculate the packet loss. So I calculated total received and total sent packets and calculated their difference as sum('packetSent:count')-sum('packetReceived:count'). But this value turns out to be a negative value for me. Any idea why?

Comment: Where do you measure this statistic in the network stack? And what kind of traffic is in the network? Because it is feasible that some applications/nodes receive more packets than they send (for example, UDP packets). The statistic for packet loss defined this way makes sense for ping packets, for example (if you measure it at the ping app). It might also make sense to take the number of sent packets at a traffic source and subtract the number of received packets at the destination node.

Comment: And also, the difference between the number of sent and received packets are not the loss, because a lot of packets might in transit or sitting temporarily in queues. Those are not lost packets as they will eventually be delivered.

Comment: I am using a UDPBasic app. And if it is not the difference, how else can we get the packet loss in this case? The routing path is from the switch to the hub, and the hub to the lamps, via multiple hops.